# video concatenation using python breaks video in chunks

Tags: python, video, concatenation, video-processing, moviepy

Hi so we are using python to concatenate two videos together but we are facing issue to make the video visible on android and iOS device. By using this the second video which needs to be attached in the end, breaks down into small chunks and becomes distorted.  I have attached the output of the video also. Watch the last five seconds of that video.

Output : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uwhUG03Q_92QmHiFd_VrecBwbWGTfwvP/view

we are using this :

```
# Import everything needed to edit video clips
    from moviepy.editor import *

# loading video dsa gfg intro video
    clip = VideoFileClip("v4.mp4")

# getting subclip as video is large
    clip1 = clip.subclip(0, 5)


# loading video gfg
    clipx = VideoFileClip("v3.mp4")

# getting subclip
    clip2 = clipx.subclip(0, 3)
    clip2.ipython_display(width = 480)

# clip list
    clips = [clip1, clip2]

# concatenating both the clips
    final = concatenate_videoclips(clips)

#final_clip.write_videofile("new.mp4")

# showing final clip
    final.ipython_display(width = 480)
```

Comment: I don't use Python or MoviePy but: **(1)** Are you saying the video plays fine [on desktop] but then only distorts when re-played in Android and iOS? **(2)** Are both videos having same resolution, framerate and also similar H264 settings (like same Profile, colorspace, etc). Check with a tool like MediaInfo. **(3)** In MPEG video you can't just join bytes of different/random H264 types. You might need to **re-encode** a new output video. Or better is to re-encode the second to match the settings of first video, then concat should work.